# Magento Configurable Product Rating Block Simple Product

Tags: php, magento

I currently have Magento configurable products showing simple product reviews with no problem.

The issue is that the rating block or star rating is not updating.  Looking at the code it uses

/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Block/View.php

The function is getRating.

```
public function getRating()
    {
        if( !$this->getRatingCollection() ) {
            $ratingCollection = Mage::getModel('rating/rating_option_vote')
                ->getResourceCollection()
                ->setReviewFilter($this->getReviewId())
                ->setStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->addRatingInfo(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->load();
            $this->setRatingCollection( ( $ratingCollection->getSize() ) ? $ratingCollection : false );
        }
        return $this->getRatingCollection();
    }
```

Any idea on how the filters would be modified to get the total rating for all configurations of the product?